# Implementing a rate limited search results using `Observable`s

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive

Let's say I have two `Observable`s:
`obs1` emits results of user input in a search box,
`obs2` takes a string as an input and initiates an HTTP request, then provides a result

Now, I want to limit the number of HTTP requests not by some constant time interval but depending on when an `obs2` is done with a current request, something like this:

1. User types `t`, `obs2` immediately starts a request with `t`
2. User types `te`, `obs2` is still "busy", nothing happens
3. User types `tes`, `obs2` is still "busy", nothing happens
4. User types `test`, `obs2` is still "busy", nothing happens
5. `t`-HTTP response has arrived, `obs2` is now "free", it looks at `obs1` last emitted value and finds `test`, starts a new request
6. `test`-HTTP response has arrived, `obs2` is now "free", it looks at `obs1` last emitted value and finds `test`, does nothing because the value has not changed.

I could do this by introducing additional variables which would indicate a state of the system and a search query accumulator but I wonder if this could be done in purely functional way i.e. by using `rxJava` methods alone?

Comment: You know this could end up with a near 2x latency delay? Wouldn't it be better to issue multiple web requests to avoid long delays for the end user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code and comment.

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;
import xdean.jex.extra.Pair;

public class Q43975663 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    PublishSubject<String> textSub = PublishSubject.create(); // emit user input text
    PublishSubject<String> taskSub = PublishSubject.create(); // emit when execution thread is free
    // core
    Observable
        // when new text input or execution thread change to free, emit an item
        .combineLatest(textSub.distinctUntilChanged(), taskSub, Pair::of)
        // if the text not change or task cycle not change, ignore it
        .scan((p1, p2) ->
            (p1.getLeft().equals(p2.getLeft()) || p1.getRight().equals(p2.getRight())) ?
                p1 : p2)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        // map to user input text
        .map(Pair::getLeft)
        // scheduler to IO thread
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        // do HTTP request
        .doOnNext(Q43975663::httpTask)
        // emit item to notify the execution thread is free
        .doOnNext(taskSub::onNext)
        .subscribe();
    // test
    taskSub.onNext("start");
    textSub.onNext("t");
    textSub.onNext("te");
    textSub.onNext("tex");
    textSub.onNext("text");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    textSub.onNext("new");
    textSub.onNext("new");
    textSub.onNext("text");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  }

  static void httpTask(String id) {
    System.out.printf("%s \tstart on \t%s\n", id, Thread.currentThread());
    try {
      Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.printf("%s \tdone on \t%s\n", id, Thread.currentThread());
  }
}
```

Note `Pair` is a simple class with two values, left and right.

output:

```
t       start on    Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
t       done on     Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
text    start on    Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
text    done on     Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
new     start on    Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
new     done on     Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
text    start on    Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
text    done on     Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
```